# Dynamicaly import an svg file in My VueJS component

Tags: vue.js

I want to do something like that :

import '~/path/to/svg/${props_here}.svg';

is that possible in vue-js ?

Answer (score 0):

try the following then:

```
<component v-bind:is="componentFile"></component>

props: {
        componentName: {
            type: String
        }
    }
    computed: {
        componentFile() {
            return () => import(`./path/${this.componentName}.vue`);
        }
    }
```

Comment: That won't work for me coz I'm using a custom component, that has on its template '<svg ....> </svg>' , so I must import the icon on my component.

Comment: I've updated my answer, can you please share more code.

Comment: <template>
<svg>
<use xlink:href': `#${iconName}` <use>
</svg>
</template>
<script>
export default {
name:  ‘IconComponent',
props: {
iconName: {
type: String,
required: true,
},
};
</script>